# How to simulate elevation using Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, gps, location, gpx

I need to be able to test an elevation across two apps on my iPhone. One is mine, another is a 3rd party app that will commonly be used in association with mine. My app relies on elevation, but the primary navigation is via the 3rd party mapping app. I need to be able to transition between the two apps and have the altitude be confirmed in my app (and when certain elevations are reached at certain locations, something is unlocked).

I have been using GPX files to simulate location thus far to get my basic setup going, but Xcode does not support the `<ele>1234</ele>` tag, it always reports `0`.

I have seen [GpxLocationManager](https://github.com/vermont42/GpxLocationManager), but it only allows me to simulate my app's location/elevation.

Is there any other way to simulate my elevation on the entire device?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Cheers.

Comment: @epologee, unfortunately, I have not. Likewise, if you come across a solution, please let me know. This is still of interest to me.